# trying to understand church encoding in Scheme

Tags: scheme, lambda-calculus, church-encoding

I'm trying to understand the whole principal of church encoding through Scheme. I *think* I understand the basics of it such as

- Church numeral for 0

  (define c-0
  (lambda (f)
  (lambda (x)
  x)))
- Church numeral for 1

  (define c-1
  (lambda (f)
  (lambda (x)
  (f x))))

... and continue applying the function to x N times.

Now my problem is just what does this all mean? If I take church-3 for example:

```
(define c-3
  (lambda (x)
    (lambda (f)
      (f (f (f x))))))
```

What is this actually doing? I have only basic scheme knowledge as well but I don't even understand how to use the function? what is an example input using the c-3 function? is it just applying something 3 times like a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. c-3 in this case is a function, that takes 1 argument. And returns another function.
This other function takes a 1 argument function, and applies it to the first argument.

In this example, I'm calling c-3 with an argument of 3, this will return a function. 
Then, I feed this function, another function, that add1 to x.

```
((c-3 3) (lambda (x) (add1 x)))
6
```

This will produce `6` as you see. It applies add1 to 3, 3 times. I know this is confusing. But you can
manually replace the arguments in the body of the function to understand it better. Wherever you see f, just replace that with `(lambda (x) (add1 x))` And replace `x` with `3` (or any number).

This will work with any 1 argument function as long as the argument is of the correct type.